# How can I remove the gray-scale page background of a PDF document scan while preserving the text? (Binarization)

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, image-processing

My PDF contains 600 pages with images of text.
It has **2 layers**.

- Layer 1: Background colour image
- Layer 2: Text image

I would like to remove all background image layers in the total PDF file as shown in the image.

[image]

Could you suggest me any software/tool?

[image]

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10, 64-bit.

Comment: Question description updated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get printer-ready black text on white background in scanned pdf files (remove grayscale or color background)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1359605/get-printer-ready-black-text-on-white-background-in-scanned-pdf-files-remove-gr)

Answer (score 11):

### Overview

What you are looking for are tools like [Scan Tailor](http://scantailor.org/) and [unpaper](http://unpaper.berlios.de/) that are capable of [Thresholding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_(image_processing)), [Despeckling, and Noise Removal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Despeckling). Both tools work with images rather than PDF files but you can easily convert between the different formats these applications use and PDF by using the tools described at the end of this answer.

#### [ScanTailor](https://github.com/scantailor/scantailor/)

You can find a video tutorial [here](http://vimeo.com/12524529). More extensive documentation is available on the [official wiki](https://github.com/scantailor/scantailor/wiki/User-Guide). You will probably be most interested in the page on [black and white output mode and filter settings](https://github.com/scantailor/scantailor/wiki/Output).

**Note**: [Since ~2016](https://github.com/scantailor/scantailor/graphs/code-frequency)

> This project is no longer maintained, and has not been maintained for a while.

Check [ScanTailor Advanced](https://github.com/4lex4/scantailor-advanced).

#### [Unpaper](https://www.flameeyes.com/projects/unpaper)

I haven't worked with `unpaper` myself, yet. From what I understand it has far more features than ScanTailor but it's also much harder to master.

There is no GUI interface and you will have to rely on command line switches to get your work done. On the other hand this means that conversions with `unpaper` can easily be automated using scripts.

You can find some scripting examples concerning converting a scan to black and white and removing the background [here](http://www.auditeon.com/software:unpaper_test).

### Installation

This command will install all of the tools mentioned above:

```
sudo apt-get install scantailor unpaper poppler-utils libtiff-tools
```

### Helpful tools when working with unpaper and ScanTailer

I don't have enough time to write up a full tutorial on ScanTailor and unpaper<sup>[1](https://github.com/4lex4/scantailor-advanced)</sup> but here are some pointers concerning converting between `.pdf` and the image formats supported by these tools:

- You can use [`pdfimages`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/pdfimages.1.html) to convert PDF documents to single page `.ppm` files, which can be read by `unpaper`.

  Usage example:

  ```bsh
  pdfimages *.pdf ./extracted-images
  ```
- ScanTailor doesn't take `.ppm` files as an input. You will have to convert them to another format like the loss-less `.png`first. [`mogrify`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/mogrify.1.html) out of the  `imagemagick` tool suite can do this for you.

  Usage example:

  ```
  mogrify -format png *.ppm
  ```
- The output format of ScanTailor and unpaper are single page `.tiff` files. In order to convert them back to `.pdf` I would suggest using [`tiffcp`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/tiffcp.1.html) and [`tiff2pdf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/tiff2pdf.1.html).

  Usage example:

  ```
  tiffcp *.tiff all.tiff
  tiff2pdf -F -p A4 -z -o Document.pdf all.tiff
  ```

---

<sup>[1](https://github.com/4lex4/scantailor-advanced)</sup>: To anyone reading this, please feel free to compile a more extensive answer based on ScanTailor and/or unpaper.

Comment: Scantailer works but on pdf files. You would have to cinvert it to some image format first.

Comment: @ToDo Yes, as pointed out in the answer :).

Comment: I realised now. It's better to organise the answer so that all information on each program is in one block.

Comment: @ToDo The original reason why I put the tools in a spearate section was because they were relevant to both unpaper and Scantailor. You're right, though, it was a bit unorganized. I think it should be better now

Comment: The question does not concern image processing. It is stated that the PDF somehow already has separate layers, and the question is about removing a specific layer from all pages of a PDF document.

Comment: Otherwise, there is this question: [*Need to improve the quality of images with GIMP*](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/132865).

Answer (score 7):

### [gscan2pdf](http://gscan2pdf.sourceforge.net/)

I just found a very simple solution:

1. Install `gscan2pdf`.
2. Open `gscan2pdf`, and import the PDF.
3. Tools->threshold. The default of 80% worked fine for me.

   > **Threshold**: Changes all pixels darker than the given value to black; all others become white.
4. Save the PDF in another location.

Comment: The question does not concern image processing. It is stated that the PDF somehow already has separate layers, and the question is about removing a specific layer from all pages of a PDF document.

Comment: The tool "Brightness/Contrast" worked better than "Threshold" in my case (crumpled paper)

Answer (score 3):

### [OCRmyPDF](https://github.com/jbarlow83/OCRmyPDF)

I tried [Ocrmypdf](https://github.com/jbarlow83/OCRmyPDF) to remove the gray background color, it worked for me. Command I tried:

```
ocrmypdf --use-threads \
         --remove-background \
         -v2 \
         --force-ocr \
         --optimize 3 \
         --output-type pdf \
         in.pdf out.pdf
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/)

You can use [`convert` or `mogrify` (in place)](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php). Just one command:

```
mogrify -type grayscale -gamma "2" -normalize -contrast -contrast -contrast foo.pdf
```

Changed the mode to grayscale, [gamma correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction) to 2, normalize (check also [`-auto-level`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#auto-level) and [`-equalize`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?ImageMagick=quc2uajippmh7ab07lp92csoo4#equalize); `-normalize` is equivalent to [`-contrast-stretch 0.15x0.05%`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#contrast-stretch)), some contrast.. The result with your example:

[image: screenshot]

This is with IMv6. With IMv7 all will be used with `magick`. [A quote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61208844/4970442) from https://imagemagick.org/script/porting.php#cli:

> `animate`, `compare`, `composite`, `conjure`, `convert`, `display`, `identify`, `import`, `mogrify`, `montage`, `stream`
>
> To reduce the footprint of the command-line utilities, these utilities are symbolic links to the `magick` utility. You can also invoke them from the `magick` utility, for example, use `magick convert logo: logo.png` to invoke the `magick` utility.
> [...]
> With the IMv7 parser, activated by the `magick` utility, settings are applied to each image in memory in turn (if any). While an option: only need to be applied once globally. Using the other utilities directly, or as an argument to the `magick` CLI (e.g. `magick convert`) utilizes the legacy parser.

Check also:

- `-threshold 60%`, `-trim`, `-background`, `-level 10%,90% -sharpen 0x1`.
- [pdfsandwich](http://www.tobias-elze.de/pdfsandwich/index.html): *Tool to generate "sandwich" OCR pdf files*.
- Reduce PDF size:

  ```
  gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
  ```

Comment: `mogrify -type grayscale -gamma "2" -normalize -contrast -contrast -contrast foo.pdf` - this command produces very low quality text: gray background gone, but the font is very choppy and hard to read, almost unreadable.

Comment: @LexxLuxx YMMV, depends on the input images. Did you try playing with the other options, like `-threshold` and `level`?

Comment: I used: `convert in.jpg -type grayscale -normalize -level 15%,75% out.jpg`. This produces more or less acceptable result. Does `-type grayscale` option is somewhat helpful here?

Answer (score 0):

maybe [Master PDF editor](http://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor.php) can help you, although I haven't found anyway to do this automatically over the 600 pages.